# Show confidence score for each word in the transcription Google Speech API

Tags: google-speech-api

I am trying to print the confidence score of each word and not just the full sentence, as it currently shows. How should it be done?

Currently, this is my output:

```html
Transcript:  Okay. Thank you so much for bye-bye.
Confidence: 0.93427926302
Word: Okay., start_time: 1500.9, end_time: 1501.5
Word: Thank, start_time: 1501.5, end_time: 1501.8
Word: you, start_time: 1501.8, end_time: 1501.9
Word: so, start_time: 1501.9, end_time: 1502.1
Word: much, start_time: 1502.1, end_time: 1502.1
Word: for, start_time: 1502.1, end_time: 1502.3
Word: bye-bye., start_time: 1502.3, end_time: 1502.9
```

I want to know the confidence score for each word!

Answer (score 1):

(Don't have enough reputation to make a comment yet)

I see you are getting the `start_time` and `end_time`.  Are you getting this from the `WordInfo` API? If you aren't, I suggest you take a look at it ([link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#wordinfo)).

In the V1 version of the API, `WordInfo` has a `confidence` field that looks like it is per word*.  You didn't say what language, method (REST vs grpc) or API version you using, but I hope this helps some.

*I just started learning the Google Speech API this week and haven't used this feature yet. Take what I say with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like word level confidence is currently part of the v1p1beta version of the API only.

See the `enableWordConfidence` option in the beta docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig).